# Android app not receiving location updates

Tags: android, maps, locationlistener

I'm trying to run an app that updates and centers the location from the device on the map fragment displayed on screen. 
The blue dot on the map is displayed on the correct position, and the gps location is locked, but it seems that the onLocationChanged function is never called.

EDIT: Things are getting even weirder now. I left the app running for a while (around 10 minutes) and it did updated it's location a couple of times at random. and it suddenly stopped again. At least i know the functions are correct. But now where should i look?

Below is the relevant code.

```
public class MapaActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

public static GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


}

public boolean setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (mMap == null) {

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (mMap == null) {

            setUpMap();

        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void setUpMap() {

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LocationManager locationManager;

    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0  , this);

}



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    //do some stuff

}
```

Comment: the return type for `setUpMapIfNeeded` must be void.

Comment: I actualyy use the information returned from the setup map function in order to check if it is already set, before doing some other assignments to the map frame

Comment: But you are not doing it.

Comment: It's on an omited function.

Comment: Things are getting even weirder now. It did updated it's location a couple of times at random. and it suddenly stopped again. At least i know the functions are correct. But now where should i look?

Answer (score 0):

Because **you are not correctly registering for location udpates**.

I dont know why you are checking `mMap == null` but try this:

```
if (mMap != null) {

            setUpMap();

        }
```

Comment: I try to get the mMap using the fragment for it. If it's still null after the attempt, it calls for the setUpMap function.

Comment: That is not correct, you should continue if the map is not null try the answer.

Comment: It didn't fixed my problem. But shouldn't the logic be "If null, try to get from here, if it's still null, setup again"?

Comment: I mean, it's inside setUpMap() that i define the mMap. Shouldn't it be called only if mMap is null?

Comment: but you have already instantiated it before the above condition.

Comment: I'ts because I haven't posted the complete code. The setUpMapIfNeeded() is called inside the onResume() - and onCreate - to make sure the map fragment is not null before proceeding with the rest of the code. 
It checks if the mMap is already instanciated, if positive it returns true. If not, it tries to retrieve the map from the fragment, if it fails and mMap still is null, it then calls for the setUpMap(), where it's recreated.